# Excel Control events trigger on application close

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I've an Excel-workbook with ActiveX controls on worksheets (not on Userform!). When I close the workbook (without closing Excel) everything works well, but when I close Excel entirely it triggers Change events of ActiveX Comboboxes on the worksheets. This creates errors because it seems that Excel has done some cleaning already by removing controls.

How can I bypass or solve this? These events shouldn't trigger in the first place because no values are changed on close.

Comment: do you have any event in your ActiveX that would get triggered on Excel Close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing how your ActiveX controls are setup I can't tell you why their change events are firing.  However, assuming the workbook's BeforeClose event fires before the ActiveX change events, you can add a global variable to track when the workbook is closing.

In a code module:

```
Public g_bClosingWorkbook As Boolean
```

In ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   g_bClosingWorkbook = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   g_bClosingWorkbook = False
End Sub
```

Then only run the change events if not closing the workbook.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
   If Not g_bClosingWorkbook Then
      ' do stuff here
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is what I do now. Had hope there would be a nicer solution.

Comment: Even this approach didn't work for us properly, not sure why, though I'll note in our case the workbook was prompting whether to save or not (with a "no" response) which resulted in it not working.  In our case the global variable was being reset back to False during the workbook shutdown (by Excel, somehow), *after* it was set to True in the Workbook_BeforeClose, resulting the offending event handlers still being erroneously fired.  To work around this we inverted the logic, that is the boolean gets set to True in the _Open() method and _Change() handers only operate if the value is True.

Answer (score 2):

Insert this sub into a module and use it to save and close both the workbook and Excel. Events are disabled first which should prevent the problem.

```
Sub closeNoEvents()
   Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.Quit
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

You also might check to see what code is in "ThisWorkbook"; maybe there is something in `Workbook_BeforeClose`.

Comment: Application.EnableEvents = False does not prevent control events from triggering.